# Upsampling (disaggregating) summed quarterly data to monthly data

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, resampling

I am trying to upsample data from aggregated quarterly up to monthly, but the numbers that below code produces are not what I need. I would need these data points to be disaggregated into monthly numbers (that add back up to the immediately following quarter). So each new value would need to be about a third of the following quarter.

```
i = ['2000-01-01','2000-04-01','2000-07-01','2000-10-01','2001-01-01','2001-04-01','2001-07-01','2001-10-01']
d = [0,54957.84767,0,0,0,56285.54879,0,0]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=i, data=d)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,infer_datetime_format=True)
df.index = df.index.to_period('Q')

df.resample('M').first().interpolate(method='cubic')
```

UPDATE: Let's say a toy series is [0,0,9]. So January, February, March. The value at the end of March is 9. I would like the interpolated result to be [3,3,3]. So every month has the value of 3, and when you aggregate them back into quarters it results in a 9 again.

Comment: Thanks - updated the question!

Comment: What you want is not possible without a third data point. A company usually has exponential growth, but to fit an exponential curve you need at least three points. With two points you can only do linear interpolation and then possibly extrapolate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not really possible with only two data points. A company usually has some polynomial or exponential growth, but with only two data points you cannot fit an such a complex growth curve. Only linear interpolation would be possible.

But let's assume you have a third point

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.date_range('2000-4-1', periods=3, freq='4Q') # quarter _end_!
Qsales = [54957.84767, 56285.54879, 58277.10047]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter sales':Qsales}, index=pd.Index(date, name='date'))
print(df)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.index, df['Quarter sales'])
plt.show()
```

This shows:

```
            Quarter sales
date                     
2000-06-30    54957.84767
2001-06-30    56285.54879
2002-06-30    58277.10047
```

[image]

Now we can do something. Let's fit an exponential curve according to `y = offset + factor * base^x`.
edit: I'm using `pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1)` as a zero-point here.

```
#### curve fitting
import numpy as np
date_delta = (date - pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1)) /np.timedelta64(1,'M')
## convert data to x/y
x = date_delta.values
y = df['Quarter sales'].values
## expected function
def expFunc(x, offset, factor, base) : return offset + factor * base**x
## initial guess
guess = (53000, 1000, 1.05)
## call scipy curve fitting
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
params = curve_fit(expFunc, x, y, guess)
## now first generate data for all quarters using interpolation
# generate new dates
date = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=3*4, freq='Q') # quarter _end_!
date_delta = (date - pd.datetime(2000,1,1)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
x = date_delta.values
Qsales = expFunc(x, params[0][0], params[0][1], params[0][2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter sales':Qsales}, index=pd.Index(date, name='date'))
print(df)
plt.plot(df.index, df['Quarter sales'])
plt.show()
```

This gives:

```
            Quarter sales
date                     
2000-03-31   54702.538666
2000-06-30   54957.847670
2000-09-30   55243.580457
2000-12-31   55560.059331
2001-03-31   55902.585284
2001-06-30   56285.548790
2001-09-30   56714.147971
2001-12-31   57188.866281
2002-03-31   57702.655211
2002-06-30   58277.100470
2002-09-30   58919.999241
2002-12-31   59632.076706
```

[image]

Now that smooths things out. But that's still not enough. You need to determine the sales per month. Well, because you now know the curve, you can distribute the growth per month according to:

```
#now further interpolate to months
date = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=3*12, freq='M') # month _end_!
date_delta = (date - pd.datetime(2000, 1, 1)) / np.timedelta64(1,'M')
x = date_delta.values
# first determine the exponential factor per month
dateFactors = expFunc(x, params[0][0], params[0][1], params[0][2])
MFactorSeries = pd.Series(dateFactors, index=date)
# now sum the exponential factors to get them for the quarters
QFactorSeries = MFactorSeries.resample('Q').sum()
# and divide them by the quartarly sales to get a monthly sales base 
MSalesBase = np.divide(Qsales, QFactorSeries.values) 
#now some numpy tricks to get the monthly sales
Msales = np.multiply(dateFactors.reshape(12,3), MSalesBase.reshape(12,1)).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Monthly sales':Msales}, index=pd.Index(date, name='date'))
print(df)
plt.plot(df.index, df['Monthly sales'])
plt.show()
```

This gives:

```
            Monthly sales
date                     
2000-01-31   18208.780004
2000-02-29   18233.319078
2000-03-31   18260.439584
2000-04-30   18290.245845
2000-05-31   18319.272021
2000-06-30   18348.329804
2000-07-31   18382.360436
2000-08-31   18414.515147
2000-09-30   18446.704874
2000-10-31   18484.774541
2000-11-30   18519.227954
2000-12-31   18556.056836
2001-01-31   18596.904560
2001-02-28   18632.486725
2001-03-31   18673.193999
2001-04-30   18718.262419
2001-05-31   18761.833781
2001-06-30   18805.452590
2001-07-31   18856.427507
2001-08-31   18904.698469
2001-09-30   18953.021996
2001-10-31   19010.040490
2001-11-30   19061.766635
2001-12-31   19117.059156
2002-01-31   19178.229496
2002-02-28   19231.653416
2002-03-31   19292.772298
2002-04-30   19360.251134
2002-05-31   19425.676408
2002-06-30   19491.172928
2002-07-31   19567.484781
2002-08-31   19639.973435
2002-09-30   19712.541026
2002-10-31   19797.887582
2002-11-30   19875.573492
2002-12-31   19958.615633
```

[image]

## Note

I'm no expert on pandas, scipy, numpy, etc. This is just how I should do it using my engineering background.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. This covers a part of my problem but it's due to the way I wrote it, not due to your solution. What you posted does answer the question as asked however so I will accept it as answered and post a new question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but `method=cubic` is not working due to NaN's.

```
df.resample('M').asfreq().interpolate()
```

Output:

```
                    0
2000-01      0.000000
2000-02  18319.282557
2000-03  36638.565113
2000-04  54957.847670
2000-05  36638.565113
2000-06  18319.282557
2000-07      0.000000
2000-08      0.000000
2000-09      0.000000
2000-10      0.000000
2000-11      0.000000
2000-12      0.000000
2001-01      0.000000
2001-02  18761.849597
2001-03  37523.699193
2001-04  56285.548790
2001-05  37523.699193
2001-06  18761.849597
2001-07      0.000000
2001-08      0.000000
2001-09      0.000000
2001-10      0.000000
2001-11      0.000000
2001-12      0.000000
```

Comment: But what about the missing months? or does it only convert those that have adjacent quarterly values?

Comment: Missing months?  Which months are missing?

Comment: all the zeroed ones - 2000 July to December for example.

Comment: You have zeros in there so it interpolates to the zero.  I guess this is why you wanted to use cubic.  I understand now.

Comment: I suppose if I first interpolated the quarters (without resampling) that would fill in the missing quarters. From then I could resample to months and then interpolate a second time, that might do it.

Comment: Ah... that way you eliminate the zeroes.  Yes, I can see that.

Comment: Although this still leaves me with the exact same problem - the values are not being disaggregated. For example 2000-04 is 54957 and it should be a third of that. So interpolate fills in the adjacent values but does not adjust the original input values. @scott-boston